# How to catch async void method exception?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have an implementation like this:

```c#
Task<IEnumerable<Item1>> GetItems1() 
{
    return RunRequest(async () => ParseItemsFromResponse(await(httpClient.Get(..))));
}

Task<IEnumerable<Item2>> GetItems2() 
{
    return RunRequest(async () => ParseItemsFromResponse(await httpClient.Get(..)));
}


TResult RunRequest<TResult>(Func<TResult> req)
{
    try
    {
        return req();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Parse exception here and throw custom exceptions
    }
}
```

The issue is the void anonymous method `async () => ParseItemsFromResponse(..)`.

Since it returns void and not a `Task`, if there's an exception thrown within the anonymous method, it's actually not going to be caught by the `try` and `catch` within the `RunRequest`.

Any suggestions how to refactor this?

Comment: Just *don't* use `async void`. They are only meant for event handlers or similar methods that can't receive or handle a `Task` result. You can't an exception thrown by `async void` except  by the application's Unhandled Exception handler

Comment: Generally it's advised *never* to use void with async functions.

Comment: Make `RunRequest` take a `Task` instead of `Func` and pass in the `httpClient.Get()` directly?

Comment: The compiler wouldn't use that `RunRequest` overload unless ParseItemsFromResponse returns something. Do you have another one for `Action` ? Just don't do it like this. `var result=await httpClient.Get();ParseItems(result);` is cleaner

Comment: @Mats391 that's a good idea, why I didn't think about it, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RunRequest` should take a `Func<Task<TResult>>`, as such:

```
async Task<TResult> RunRequestAsync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> req)
{
  try
  {
    return await req().ConfigureAwait(false);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // Parse exception here and throw custom exceptions
  }
}
```

Then your `async` lambdas are converted to `async Task<T>` methods instead of `async void`.

I have more information on [sync/async delegates](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/02/synchronous-and-asynchronous-delegate.html) on my blog.

Comment: Is it necessary to also call `ConfigureAwait(false)` ?  Or is it just an optimization not to switch context back?

Comment: @DonBox: It's just an optimization.